# Why are actions/workflow not running on Pull Requests from collaborators?

Tags: github, github-actions

My account has "collaborator" status on another user's repository. When I create (or add commits to) a PR from a branch on my fork to the master branch of the upstream repository the actions/workflows are not run. I am not a first time contributor to the repository.

My understanding is that PRs from forks will not be run without approval ([per these docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/approving-workflow-runs-from-public-forks)) but it is not clear to me if being added as a "collaborator" on the repository by the owner should skip the need for approval. Furthermore, the default setting appears to be that approval is only required for first-time contributors.

I do see workflow runs are started for each commit in my fork so I know my workflow is valid. I just need the workflow to also run on the upstream repository so that the status/result of the run is displayed on the Pull Request page.

What are the possible causes of this?

For reference, here is the first few lines of the workflows that I expect to be run on each push.

```
name: CI

on: [ push ]

jobs:
    ... etc ...
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
  pull_request:
```

`on push` is not enough as forks push to... forks, not the origin repo.

This will run the workflow:

- on any push to master (for example merge or a direct push) (only origin)
- on most PR updates (open / reopen / update) (origin or fork to origin)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your second line should be updated to `on: [ pull_request ]`